# Find steady-state of a set of differential equations

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

Let us assume I have a set of differential equations to be integrated with scipy odeint. Now my goal is to find the steady-state (I chose initial conditions such that this state exists). At the moment I have implemented something like

```
cond = True
while cond:
    x = integrate(interval = [0,t], steps = 200)
    if var(x[-22::]) < maxvar:
        cond = False
        return mean(x)
    else:
       t*= 2
```

Do you have a more efficient approach?

Comment: This really depends on the definition of steady state!
I.E. Consider an oscillating circuit with constant frequency, and constant amplitude.. while that does not conform to the standard definition dx/dt = 0, it remains a constant in the laplace domain...

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. Let us just assume a very conservative case with x=const up to small oscillations.

Comment: even more nitpicking (sorry) but what do you mean with efficient? - fast or with very little false positives?  Let me refer you to this article discussing the problems of detecting steadystate: http://prism.groups.et.byu.net/uploads/Members/kelly_jpc2013.pdf

Comment: Henrik: In my particular case it can be proven that there is exactly one steady state with a specific height. Hence I am rather interested in efficiency with respect to speed and precission!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using [`odeint`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html), then you already have your differential equations written as a function `f(x, t)` (or possibly `f(x, t, *args)`).  If your system is autonomous (i.e. `f` does not actually depend on `t`), you can find an equilibrium by solving `f(x, 0) == 0` for `x`.  You can use, for example, [`scipy.optimize.fsolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) to solve for the equilibrium.

The following is an example.  It uses the ["Coupled Spring Mass System" example from the scipy cookbook](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/CoupledSpringMassSystem).  `scipy.optimize.fsolve` is used to find the equilibrium solution `x1 = 0.5`, `y1 = 0`, `x2 = 1.5`, `y2 = 0`.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


def vectorfield(w, t, p):
    """
    Defines the differential equations for the coupled spring-mass system.

    Arguments:
        w :  vector of the state variables:
                  w = [x1, y1, x2, y2]
        t :  time
        p :  vector of the parameters:
                  p = [m1, m2, k1, k2, L1, L2, b1, b2]
    """
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = w
    m1, m2, k1, k2, L1, L2, b1, b2 = p

    # Create f = (x1', y1', x2', y2'):
    f = [y1,
         (-b1 * y1 - k1 * (x1 - L1) + k2 * (x2 - x1 - L2)) / m1,
         y2,
         (-b2 * y2 - k2 * (x2 - x1 - L2)) / m2]
    return f


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Parameter values
    # Masses:
    m1 = 1.0
    m2 = 1.5
    # Spring constants
    k1 = 8.0
    k2 = 40.0
    # Natural lengths
    L1 = 0.5
    L2 = 1.0
    # Friction coefficients
    b1 = 0.8
    b2 = 0.5

    # Pack up the parameters and initial conditions:
    p = [m1, m2, k1, k2, L1, L2, b1, b2]

    # Initial guess to pass to fsolve.  The second and fourth components
    # are the velocities of the masses, and we know they will be 0 at
    # equilibrium.  For the positions x1 and x2, we'll try 1 for both.
    # A better guess could be obtained by solving the ODEs for some time
    # interval, and using the last point of that solution.
    w0 = [1.0, 0, 1.0, 0]

    # Find the equilibrium
    eq = fsolve(vectorfield, w0, args=(0, p))

    print "Equilibrium: x1 = {0:.1f}  y1 = {1:.1f}  x2 = {2:.1f}  y2 = {3:.1f}".format(*eq)
```

The output is:

```
Equilibrium: x1 = 0.5  y1 = 0.0  x2 = 1.5  y2 = 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your comments, I don't see any better way:

In this case where you know approximately where the system will settle.
(This is fairly easy to predict in some systems, like a pendulum, or a charging capacitor), and that it will settle, the fastest way I know is to check if

```
(p[0] * x[i] + p[1] * x[i-1] ... + p[n] * x[i-n]  - mean(x[i-0:n]) )< epsilon)
```

The difficulty is determining the size of epsilon, the parameters p[0:n] to tune this detection.

Clearly you are already using this window method:

```
epsilon = varmax
p[0:n] = 1
n = 22
```

and have optimized it by removing the parameters for the filter, and simply using the variance.

For many systems (where settling looks like 1 order differential equations) the filter parameters turn out to look like this:

```
p[0] = n/2
p[n] = n/2
p[1:n-1] = 0
```

meaning you can make stuff go faster if you replace the calculation of state variance with this simple test:

```
if( abs(x[-22] - x[0]) > epsilon)
```

This will not detect correctly if small disturbances are still present, since we don't know your system, that's difficult to talk about...